# I cant figure out how to use java gui / layouts?

Tags: java, user-interface, panel, grid-layout, flowlayout

how can I make a gui interface with everything in order I know the borderlayout, flowlayout and gridlayout but what is panel? im so confused please help in visual basic I just dragged and dropped. im using netbeans 7.1, I can do layouts and stuff the problem is its so confusing to make all these panels and stuff and (x, y) axis where to place them I want the gui nice and neat

Comment: You may start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

> how can I make a gui interface with everything in order

For a single column or row, see `GridLayout`<sup>1</sup> & `BoxLayout`<sup>2</sup>, as well as `JToolBar`<sup>3</sup> & `JList`<sup>4</sup>.

See 'How To Use':

1. [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
2. [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)
3. [JToolBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)
4. [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: im teaching myself from a book and its using JPanel row1 = new JPanel(); and everything is in perfect spot how does it do that

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these examples http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I was used to creating java GUI with manual coding, I mean not the drag and dropped that auto-generates the codes, so it was a lot easier for me to switch with GUI designer such as Window Builder plugin for Eclipse or the built-in swing designer of NetBeans.

I suggest you to start with the basic of Layout Managers with manual coding. Here's a good link... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Start with the easiest: FlowLayout, GridLayout, and BorderLayout. These layouts are usually applied to JPanel, which is a lower level container (JFrame being the top-level container)